# Apply different attribute to each element of same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

What do I need to change in my code?

Each element with the class "date_entry" should have a different attribute set, but currently all elements with that class are getting the same attribute...

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".date_entry").each(function() {
        if ($(".date_entry").attr("date", "")) {
            var date = $(this).text();
            var splitDate = date.split('/');
            var year = splitDate[2];
            var month = splitDate[0];
            var day = splitDate[1];

            var newAttr = year + month + day;
            $(".date_entry").attr("date", newAttr);
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "this" variable:

```
$(function() {
    $(".date_entry").each(function() {
            var date = $(this).text();
            var splitDate = date.split('/');
            var year = splitDate[2];
            var month = splitDate[0];
            var day = splitDate[1];

            var newAttr = year + month + day;
            $(this).attr("date", newAttr);
    });
});
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks! I also needed to remove the if statement

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $(this) instead of $(".date_entry") inside the function you are passing to each(). $(".date_entry") selects again all elements with that class.